# Store pointers to objects in multiple containers

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, containers

For the sake of presenting my question, let's assume I have a set of pointers (same type)

```
                                {p1, p2, ..., pn}
```

I would like to store them in multiple containers as I need different access strategy to access them. Suppose I want to store them in two containers, linked list and a hash table. For linked list, I have the order and for hash table I have the fast access. Now, the problem is that if I remove a pointer from one container, I'll need to remember to remove from other container. This makes the code hard to maintain. So the question is that are there other patterns or data structures to manage situation like this? Would smart pointer help here?

Comment: Yes, use a `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: No, shared_ptr doesn't solve the problem. I still need to go to two containers to deference the shared_ptr in order to delete the object. This is not desirable. I want something like if I remove the pointer in container A, the same pointer in container B will be automatically removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to link your containers so that removing from one removes from all. I don't think this is directly possible. Possible solutions:

- re-design whole object architecture, so pointer is not in many containers.
- Use [Boost Multi-index Containers Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) to achieve all features you want in one container.
- Use a map key instead of direct pointer to track objects, and keep the pointer itself in one map.
- use [`std::weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) so you can check if item has been deleted somewhere else, and turn it to [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) while it is used (you need one container to have "master" [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) to keep object around when not used)
- create function/method/class to delete objects, which knows all containers, so you don't forget accidentally, when all deletion is in one place.

Comment: Yes, you understanding is right. I voted it up, but want to leave this question open for a little longer. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it's smart to not accept an answer too soon at SO. Added a bullet for a possible Boost solution.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you create your own class which contains the both `std::list` and `std::unordred_map` and provide accessing functions and provide removal functions in a way that you can access them linearly with the `list` and randomly with the `unordred_map`, and the deletion will be deleting from both containers and insertion will insert to both. ( kind of a wrapper class :P )

Also you can consider about using `std::map`, and **providing it a comparison function** which will always keep your data structure ordered in the desired way and also you can randomly access the elements with `log N` access time.

Answer (score 2):

As usually, try to isolate this logic to make things easier to support. Some small class with safe public interface (sorry, I didn't compile this, it is just a pseudocode).

```
template<class Id, Ptr>
class Store
{
public:
   void add(Id id, Ptr ptr)
   {
      m_ptrs.insert(ptr);
      m_ptrById.insert(std::make_pair(id, ptr));
   }

   void remove(Ptr ptr)
   {
      // remove in sync as well
   }

private:
   std::list<Ptr> m_ptrs;
   std::map<Id, Ptr> m_ptrById;
};
```

Then use Store for keeping your pointers in sync.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you are less concern with memory management (new/delete issue) and more concern with the actual "book keeping" of which element is valid or not.

So, I was thinking of wrapping each point with a "reference counter"

```
 template< class Point >
 class BookKeeping {
 public:
     enum { LIST_REF = 0x01,
            HASH_REF = 0x02 };
     BookKeeping( const Point& p ): m_p(p), m_refCout( 0x3 ) {} // assume object created in both containers
     bool isValid() const { return m_refCount == 0x3; } // not "freed" from any container
     void remove( unsigned int from ) { m_refCount = m_refCount & ! from ; }
 private:
     Point m_p;
     unsigned int m_refCount;
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

See the answer (the only one, by now) to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736923/data-structures-that-have-pull-first-and-lest). In that case a `deque` is proposed instead of a `list`, since the OP only wanted to insert/remove at the ends of the sequence.

Anyway, you might prefer to use the [Boost Multi-index Containers Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).